# Wordpress slider replace with an image for the mobile screen

Tags: php, css, wordpress, slider

I'm working on this project http://color-run.giedre.dk/. I would like to replace the current slider with the image but only for the mobile version. It is a **wordpress site**. would be really greatfull if anyone can help?

Comment: Use [media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) [queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to show an HTML element or class on mobile devices and hide it on desktop devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`wp_is_mobile()`Function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) which is relatively reliable. then run CSS if it is mobile - that way you don't have to run a bunch of media queries:

```
<?php if(wp_is_mobile()) : ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

of wrap your slider in the `IF ? ELSE`

```
<?php if(!wp_is_mobile()) : ?>
    <div id="sliderWrapper">
        ...
    </div> 
<?php else : /** Is Mobile **/ ?>
    <img src="...
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No problem. If one of these answers was helpful, make sure to click the checkmark (answered) button next to the answer so that the topic is sorta marked as 'resolved'!

Answer (score 0):

Put your image underneath the slider in your HTML:

```
<img src="#" class="mobile-image">
```

Hide it in your CSS:

```
.mobile-image {
    display: none;
}
```

Hide the slider, show the image using media queries, adjust min/max width to suit your needs:

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 767px) {

    .cycloneslider {
        display: none;
    }
    .mobile-image {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - but how do I add image? since **Wordpress** stores all the images in the **database**

Comment: If you're comfortable editing your theme (use a child theme!), you can make it a featured image: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails, otherwise just upload it via FTP and write it into the theme directly. Also maybe check out http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ plugin to add a custom field for the image to your homepage.

Comment: Thank you! another issue is that I would like to hide the cyclonslider only for two pages and leave it as it on other pages, but it has the same class.Is there a way to work arround it?

Comment: You can add inline styles to those pages specifically, i.e. `<style>.cycloneslider {display: none;}</style>`